# Timer in JEE6 -> using of custom timer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer

we want to use a custom timer in a JEE6 app. Previously we used commonj.timers.TimerManager and we maked a lookup from the InitialContext.
We do not want to use the default timer, because it can be shared to several apps on the app server.

Is there a standard way to do this in JEE6? In The [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)  they use the timerservice. What is the best practice in JEE6?

Robert

Comment: I don't know what's the best practice, but I use TimerService without any problem. The timers survive restarts without any additional work.

Comment: We don't use the default timer, because applikation A can manipulate timer of application B. For this problem in  appServer we define timmer with specially jndi-name. The question is: how we get this timer.